# xpath nearest element to a given element

Tags: xpath, selenium

I am having trouble returning an element using xpath.
I need to get the text from the 2nd TD from a large table.

```
<tr> 
 <td> 
  <label for="PropertyA">Some text here </label>
 </td>
 <td> TEXT!! </td>
</tr>
```

I'm able to find the label element, but then I'm having trouble selecting the sibling TD to return the text.

This is how I select the label:

```
"//label[@for='PropertyA']"
```

thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are looking for the axes `following-sibling`. It searches in the siblings in the same parent - there it is `tr`. If the `td`s aren't in the same `tr` then they aren't found. If you want to it then you can use axes `following`.

```
//td[label[@for='PropertyA']]/following-sibling::td[1]
```

Comment: +1 for using `following-sibling` instead of `following`. The former is a more robust method - less likely to go wrong, e.g. if there is no following-sibling::td it won't select the wrong td.

Answer (score 8):

From the `label` element, it should be:

```
//label[@for='PropertyA']/following::td[1]
```

And then use the DOM method from the hosting language to get the string value.

Or select the text node (something I do not recommend) with:

```
//label[@for='PropertyA']/following::td[1]/text()
```

Or if there's going to be just this one only node, then you could use the `string()` function:

```
string(//label[@for='PropertyA']/following::td[1])
```

You can also select from the common ancestor `tr` like:

```
//tr[td/label/@for='PropertyA']/td[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting ANY following element:

//td[label[@for='PropertyA']]/following-sibling::*